# How to properly center the menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How do I properly center the menu on this page http://bit.ly/An65z5? Been poking at firebug for over an hour now, please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the float: left property from #top-menu, set the margin: 0 auto; and add a width. You can also remove the padding on the left of #top-menu as it isn't needed once the nav is centered. So it should look like the following:

```
#top-menu {
    width: 300px; /* 300px will need to change to the actual width of your nav element */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `style.css`, add the append the following lines of code in the end.

```
#top-menu {
    float: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 271px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: this will work too, although I like the ItsMIllerTime65's cleaner version better :)

Comment: yeah, cool.
I assumed you did not want to replace code, but append it in the end of the css to overwrite styles.
Anyway, work done, congrats :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid harmful need for limiting width of container, use `display: table` for centered block and `display: table-cell` for its child elements.